# I must create PHP CLASS USER with this values

Tags: php, class

I must create PHP CLASS USER with this values : id, first_name, last_name, age. 
Class must have: constructor of class 
Method that returns the name of the user
Method that returns a boolean value about user age validation
can you help me? Thanks

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Please try to make this work by yourself first, and then if you're running into issues, update the post with your code so we can try to help you out.

Comment: <?php
class User {
 var $id;
 var $first_name;
 var $last_name;
 var $age;
 function construct($id,$first_name,$last_name,$age){
  $this>=$id;
  $this>=$first_name;
  $this>=$last_name;
  $this>=$age;
 }
 function values(){
  echo "User id: {$this->id} <br/> First name : {$this->fname} <br/> Last name : {$this ->lname}";
 }
    function setAge($age){
        if(is_numeric($age) && $age >= 18){
            $this->$age = $age;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Age is not valid");
        }
    
}
}

Comment: When responding to comments asking for more information, please [edit] your question instead of responding in comments.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as correct, so others with the same problem can find the solution easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Constructor method MUST return the object itself. I think your approach is wrong. What you should do is to check the age validation in the setter of the age parameter and if it fails, raise an exception and handle it when you should. For example...

```
class User {
    private $age;

    function setAge($age){
        if(is_numeric($age) && $age >= 21){
            $this->$age = $age;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Age is not valid");
        }
    }
}
```